# Are results of (Core Data) fetch requests with predicates of [key IN $ARRAY] form ordered per the order of the array?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

See the following code:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest requestWithEntity:@"entity"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"key IN $VALUE_LIST", someNSArray];

NSError *err

NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&err];
```

Are the objects of results ordered with the same order as the objects in someNSArray that are being filtered for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. There is no guarantee of ordering unless you specify sorting or ordering criteria.

Comment: Thanks!  Suspected as much.  So filtering using any accepted collection class will behave the same, right?

Comment: Correct. You could, for example, apply sort descriptors or a filtering predicate to an array of results. Keep in mind that when the sort descriptor or predicate accesses properties of the objects in the collection it will fire faults on those objects.